# Data scraping automatically update with latest data set

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am building a shiny app for Coronavirus. 
My question is,
whenever I press the RunApp, the App should automatically take the latest data set. Here we will need to change the date before running the app every day.
How do I do it? How to put the latest date and filter the data.

This is just collecting, separating and plotting the data.

```
raw_data <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/time-series-19- 
            covid-combined.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = raw_data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
View(data)

Confirmed <- data[which(data$Date=="2020-03-18"),] %>%
  group_by(Country.Region)%>%
  summarise(Confirmed = sum(Confirmed)) %>%
  arrange(-Confirmed)
View(Confirmed)

Deaths <- data[which(data$Date=="2020-03-18"),] %>%
  group_by(Country.Region) %>%
  summarise(Deaths = sum(Deaths)) %>%
  arrange(-Deaths)
View(Deaths)

Recovered <- data[which(data$Date=="2020-03-18"),] %>%
  group_by(Country.Region) %>%
  summarise(Recovered = sum(Recovered)) %>%
  arrange(-Recovered)
View(Recovered)

Total_Confirmed <- sum(Confirmed$Confirmed)
Total_Deaths <- sum(Deaths$Deaths)
Total_Recovered <- sum(Recovered$Recovered)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sys.Date()` to print the date of today.

Example:

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2020-03-19"
```

Comment: I think I can use max function. Confirmed <- data[which(data$Date==max(data$Date),]

Answer (score 0):

Use max function to select the max date from all the dates.

```
Confirmed <- data[which(data$Date==max(data$Date),]
```